# 'activeNetworkInfo' and 'isConnectedOrConnecting' is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, deprecated

'activeNetworkInfo' and 'isConnectedOrConnecting' is deprecated.

```
/**
 * This function is used check whether the device is connected to the Internet or not.
 */
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    // It answers the queries about the state of network connectivity.
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val network      = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val activeNetWork = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network) ?: return false
        return when {
            activeNetWork.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            activeNetWork.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            //for other device how are able to connect with Ethernet
            activeNetWork.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    } else {
        /* Returns details about the currently active default data network. */
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the documentation:

> This class was deprecated in API level 29. Callers should instead use
> the ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback API to learn about
> connectivity changes, or switch to use
> ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities or
> ConnectivityManager#getLinkProperties to get information
> synchronously. Keep in mind that while callbacks are guaranteed to be
> called for every event in order, synchronous calls have no such
> constraints, and as such it is unadvisable to use the synchronous
> methods inside the callbacks as they will often not offer a view of
> networking that is consistent (that is: they may return a past or a
> future state with respect to the event being processed by the
> callback). Instead, callers are advised to only use the arguments of
> the callbacks, possibly memorizing the specific bits of information
> they need to keep from one callback to another.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo

So,you can use the NetworkCapabilities to get network connectivity state, just, change the last string in the next way:

```
return networkInfo != null && connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(n).hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
```

Details regarding `NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED` :

> Indicates that connectivity on this network was successfully
> validated. For example, for a network with NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET, it
> means that Internet connectivity was successfully detected.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED

Comment: wow thank you so much. I really do appreciate it!